# Why put asp.net MVC 5 model to another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, software-design

I read some code of asp.net MVC 5 recently.

Found that they put the model into another class library project.

Then reference that lib from another asp.net MVC 5 project within the same solution.

But I can't understand why they do that.

Why don't they put the model into the models folder of MVC project?

Instead separate them?

I do survey over the Internet but can not found concrete view point to support the way they did.

Could somebody explain the pros and cons for me?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand, you saw a single class in a shared library and the other option would be to have two copies of the very same class in two different MVC apps. And I don't think the context is clear enough to be able to support either of the two approaches.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Hi, thanks your reply!
In my opinion, the separate model class lib is for that solution only.
It's not a reusable class lib project.

In this case, how do you think?

I also see someone say that it's a good idea to separate model to another project but I don't know why.

Comment: Class lib project can be used by another project  but model folder can not

Comment: @erdiyılmaz Hi, thanks for your reply!
This opinion make sense. What if the lib contains all the business logic specific for that project? Is it still good for extract them into separate project?

Comment: I think it's much cleaner to put the classes (entities/models) in a class library project than have them reference to another MVC project. It's simpler as well, they want to make all the projects dependent on this separate Class library project, rather than have 2 or more projects dependent on another MVC project. Class Library Projects' purpose is to generally provide classes that can be used elsewhere while MVC projects are made for apps.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Hi, thanks for your reply! I agree with your opinion! In case that multiple project use the same model, it's a good idea to make code clean. What if in the case the model has business logic only for specific MVC project? Is it still worth to separate them?

Comment: @Elliot we have a few projects that does that, they all depend from the same class libraries. Yes, when we have business logic specific for this MVC project, we setup another class that inherits from the original class, and override the functionality. In this way we could keep consistency of the base class shared among the different projects.

Comment: Project developed for different teams and MVC developer cant see private function and property in model. But folder every code is open.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Thanks for sharing your experience! I think I gradually understand the benefit!